# javascript find object in nested arrays

Tags: javascript, html

```
 <html>  
    <body>  
    <script type="text/javascript">  
    var categoryGroups = [
        {
            Id: 1, Categories: 
             [
                { Id: 1 },
                { Id: 2 }, 
            ]

        },
        {
            Id: 2, Categories: [
                { Id: 100 },
                { Id: 200 },
            ]

        }
    ]

    var category, categoryGroup, found = false;
    for (i = 0; i < categoryGroups.length ; i++) {
        categoryGroup = categoryGroups[i];
        for (j = 0; j < categoryGroup.Categories.length; j++) {
            category = categoryGroup.Categories[j];
            if (category.Id === categoryGroup.Id) {
                found = true;

                break;
    window.document.write("category" );
            }
        }
        if (found) break;
    }

    </script>  
    </body>  
    </html>
```

i have created nested array.from this nested array i want print object of an nested array.but unable to find object of an nested array. how to  resolve this error?

Comment: which object like you to print?

Comment: i want to print any one object of this nested array

Comment: for example like `{ Id: 1 }`? and what do you do with `category.Id === categoryGroup.Id`?

Comment: yes.like that only

Comment: category.Id === categoryGroup.Id with this i was finding child object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `break;` below the output, because `break` ends the iteration and nothing behind gets executed.

```
window.document.write("category");
break;
```

```js
var categoryGroups = [{ Id: 1, Categories: [{ Id: 1 }, { Id: 2 }, ] }, { Id: 2, Categories: [{ Id: 100 }, { Id: 200 }, ] }],
    category, categoryGroup, found = false, i, j;

for (i = 0; i < categoryGroups.length ; i++) {
    categoryGroup = categoryGroups[i];
    for (j = 0; j < categoryGroup.Categories.length; j++) {
        category = categoryGroup.Categories[j];
        if (category.Id === categoryGroup.Id) {
            found = true;
            window.document.write("category " + category.Id); // swap
            break;                                            // lines
        }
    }
    if (found) break;
}
```

Comment: instead of Id:1.if have to print id:2.then what modification i have to do?

Comment: where do you get `2`? is it just where id is the same, but the other `Id` in the array?

Comment: from the above code i m getting output "category 1".in same way suppose i have to print "category 2".the what i have to do?

Comment: i do not understand where do you get 2?

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var categoryGroups = [
        {
            Id: 1, Categories: 
             [
                { Id: 1 },
                { Id: 2 }, 
            ]

        },
        {
            Id: 2, Categories: [
                { Id: 100 },
                { Id: 200 },
            ]

        }
    ]
categoryGroups.forEach(function(categoryGroup){
  console.log(categoryGroup.Id);
  var category = categoryGroup.Categories.filter(function(category){
  return categoryGroup.Id == category.Id
  });
   category.length && console.log(category);
})
```